# Global loaded data in VueJs is occasionally null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-mixin

I'm new to VueJs and currently trying to load some data only once and make it globally available to all vue components. What would be the best way to achieve this?
I'm a little bit stuck because the global variables occasionally seem to become *null* and I can't figure out why.

In my main.js I make three global Vue instance variables:

```
let globalData = new Vue({
  data: {
    $serviceDiscoveryUrl: 'http://localhost:40000/api/v1',
    $serviceCollection: null,
    $clientConfiguration: null
  }
});
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    $serviceDiscoveryUrl: {
      get: function () { return globalData.$data.$serviceDiscoveryUrl },
      set: function (newUrl) { globalData.$data.$serviceDiscoveryUrl = newUrl; }
    },
    $serviceCollection: {
      get: function () { return globalData.$data.$serviceCollection },
      set: function (newCollection) { globalData.$data.$serviceCollection = newCollection; }
    },
    $clientConfiguration: {
      get: function () { return globalData.$data.$clientConfiguration },
      set: function (newConfiguration) { globalData.$data.$clientConfiguration = newConfiguration; }
    }
  }
})
```

and in my App.vue component I load all the data:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data: function () {
      return {
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false
      };
    },
    methods: {
      loadAllData: function () {
        this.$axios.get(this.$serviceDiscoveryUrl)
          .then(
            response => {
              this.$serviceCollection = response.data;

              let configurationService = this.$serviceCollection.services.find(obj => obj.key == "ProcessConfigurationService");

              this.$axios.get(configurationService.address + "/api/v1/clientConfiguration").then(
                response2 => {
                  this.$clientConfiguration = response2.data;
                }
              );
              this.isLoading = false;
            })
      }
    },
    created: function m() {
      this.loadAllData();
    }
  }
</script>
```

But when I try to access the `$clientConfiguration` it seems to be `null` from time to time and I can't figure out why. For example when I try to build the navigation sidebar:

```
    beforeMount: function () {
      let $ = JQuery;
      let clients = [];
      if (this.$clientConfiguration === null)
        console.error("client config is <null>");

      $.each(this.$clientConfiguration, function (key, clientValue) {
        let processes = [];
        $.each(clientValue.processConfigurations, function (k, processValue) {
          processes.push(
            {
              name: processValue.name,
              url: '/process/' + processValue.id,
              icon: 'fal fa-project-diagram'
            });
        });

        clients.push(
          {
            name: clientValue.name,
            url: '/client/' + clientValue.id,
            icon: 'fal fa-building',
            children: processes
          });
      });

      this.nav.find(obj => obj.name == 'Processes').children = clients;
```

Comment: Why don't you put `globalData` in the global mixin ?

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work with the data in the global mixin. This "workaround" was all I could came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the `null` is just the initial value. Loading the data is asynchronous so you'll need to wait for loading to finish before trying to create any components that rely on that data.

You have an `isLoading` flag, which I would guess is your attempt to wait for loading to complete before showing any components (maybe via a suitable `v-if`). However, it currently only waits for the first request and not the second. So this:

```js
this.$axios.get(configurationService.address + "/api/v1/clientConfiguration").then(
  response2 => {
    this.$clientConfiguration = response2.data;
  }
);
this.isLoading = false;
```

would need to be:

```js
this.$axios.get(configurationService.address + "/api/v1/clientConfiguration").then(
  response2 => {
    this.$clientConfiguration = response2.data;
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
);
```

If it isn't that initial value that's the problem then you need to figure out what is setting it to `null`. That should be prety easy, just put a `debugger` statement in your setter:

```js
$clientConfiguration: {
  get: function () { return globalData.$data.$clientConfiguration },
  set: function (newConfiguration) {
    if (!newConfiguration) {
      debugger;
    }
    globalData.$data.$clientConfiguration = newConfiguration;
  }
}
```

Beyond the problem with the `null`, if you're using Vue 2.6+ I would suggest taking a look at `Vue.observable`, which is a simpler way of creating a reactive object than creating a new Vue instance.

Personally I would probably implement all of this by putting a reactive object on `Vue.prototype` rather than using a global mixin. That assumes that you even need the object to be reactive, if you don't then this is all somewhat more complicated than it needs to be.